# WPF How to convert from DataGrid to DataTable?

Tags: wpf, datatable, casting, datagrid

Hi I am following along with this [guide](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/) in order to learn about using DataGrid.

The problem I am running into is how do I convert the data from the DataGrid into a DataTable?

The code I am trying to get working is:

```
DataTable dt = ((DataView)dg.ItemsSource).ToTable();
```

but it gives me an error stating:

> Unable to cast object of type 
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WPFProject.Person]' to type
>   'System.Data.DataView'.

My code is very much similar to the example except I use the class Person instead of user and I create a list of type Person in order to insert data into the datagrid.

```
public class Person
    {
        public bool CheckBox { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't convert it that way. Your code will only work if the `ItemSource` of your `DataGrid` is not a `DataView`. You need to write code explicitly (which you can easily google any **`collection<T>` to `DataTable`**) to convert your `collection` into `DataTable`. have a look at below example:

***XAML***

```
  <StackPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding list}" x:Name="myGrid"/>
    <Button Content="convert back" Click="Button_Click_1" />
</StackPanel>
```

***Logic:***

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var list = new List<MyClass>(myGrid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable<MyClass>);
        var dataTable = ToDataTable(list);
        if (dataTable != null)
        {

        }
    }

    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

        //Get all the properties
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
        {
            //Setting column names as Property names
            dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
        }
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[Props.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
            {
                //inserting property values to datatable rows
                values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
        return dataTable;
    }
```

***Output***

[image: Grid]

[image: DataTable]

Comment: i got this error : "'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index' , my datagrid originally is filled with ObservableCollection<Cars> !! is the issue around here or ?
"

Comment: the `values = new object[Props.Length];` actually return a list full of nulls !! ,the foreach is indeed grabbing the items count and indexing correctly but not grabbing their values correctly !

Answer (score 1):

Copy past method 1

```
public static DataTable DataGridtoDataTable(DataGrid dg)
        {
dg.SelectAllCells();
            dg.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
            ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, dg);
            dg.UnselectAllCells();
            String result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);
            string[] Lines = result.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, 
            StringSplitOptions.None);
            string[] Fields;
            Fields = Lines[0].Split(new char[] { ',' });
            int Cols = Fields.GetLength(0);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //1st row must be column names; force lower case to ensure matching later on.
            for (int i = 0; i < Cols; i++)
                dt.Columns.Add(Fields[i].ToUpper(), typeof(string));
            DataRow Row;
            for (int i = 1; i < Lines.GetLength(0)-1; i++)
            {
                Fields = Lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
                Row = dt.NewRow();
                for (int f = 0; f < Cols; f++)
                {
                    Row[f] = Fields[f];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(Row);
            }
            return dt;
            
        }
```

========================================================================================

Method 2

```
public DataTable DataGridtoDataTable(DataGrid dg)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            for (int i = 0; i <= dg.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(dg.Columns[i].Header.ToString(), typeof(string));
            }
            DataRow Row;

            for (int i = 0; i <= dg.Items.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                Row = dt.NewRow();

                for (int k = 0; k <= dg.Columns.Count - 1; k++)
                {
                    Row[dg.Columns[k].Header.ToString()] = gettabelcell(i, k,dg);

                }
                dt.Rows.Add(Row);
            }

            return dt;

        }

public String gettabelcell(int x, int y,DataGrid dg)
        {
            try
            {
                String myString = dg.GetCell(x, y).ToString();

                if (myString.Contains(":"))
                {
                    String[] s = myString.Split(':');
                    String item = s[1];
                    return item.Trim();
                }
                else
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
```

this is class

```
static class ExtensionHelpers
   {

       public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
       {
           T child = default(T);
           int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
           for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
           {
               Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
               child = v as T;
               if (child == null)
               {
                   child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
               }
               if (child != null)
               {
                   break;
               }
           }
           return child;
       }

       public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, int row, int column)
       {
           DataGridRow rowContainer = grid.GetRow(row);
           return grid.GetCell(rowContainer, column);
       }
       public static DataGridRow GetSelectedRow(this DataGrid grid)
       {
           return (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(grid.SelectedItem);
       }
       public static DataGridRow GetRow(this DataGrid grid, int index)
       {
           DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
           if (row == null)
           {
               // May be virtualized, bring into view and try again.
               grid.UpdateLayout();
               grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.Items[index]);
               row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
           }
           return row;
       }

       public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, DataGridRow row, int column)
       {
           if (row != null)
           {
               DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);

               if (presenter == null)
               {
                   grid.ScrollIntoView(row, grid.Columns[column]);
                   presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
               }

               DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
               return cell;
           }
           return null;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

**To Convert DataGrid into DataTable**

1.DataGrid Itemsource are binded with list of CandidateClass.

2.Get the Item from the Itemsource of DataGrid, then serialize it into Json and Deserialize as DataTable.

```
  var Item = ListDataGrid.ItemsSource as IList<CandidateClass>;
  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Item);
  DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

Note:if DataGrid are formed based on the list of class object.This method is helpfull.

Comment: using NewtonSoft.Json;// to serialize and deserialize the object

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do that in WPF like in winforms. In Wpf, you can set the datagrid ItemsSource from a dataTable like this.

```
dg.ItemsSource = dataTable.AsDataView();
```

In your case you want to get **dataTable** from **datagrid**.
So you can try with below code.

```
DataView view = (DataView) dg.ItemsSource;
DataTable dataTable = view.Table.Clone();
foreach (var dataRowView in view)
{
    dataTable.ImportRow(dataRowView.Row);
}
var dataTableFromDataGrid = dataTable;
```