# Convert WPF DataGrid to DataTable

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I need to be able to put the **WPF datagrid** into the **datatable** after loading and filling the datagrid. After searching in Google, I came across the code that Datagrid should be cast to Dataview.

This code is loading datagrid:

```
 private void LoadDataGrid()
    {
        using (famloanEntities db = new famloanEntities())
        {
                var ash = db.Ashkhas;

                DataGrid1.ItemsSource = ash.ToList();

        }
    }
```

I use this code to convert the datagrid to the datatable:

```
  DataTable dt = ((DataView)DataGrid1.ItemsSource).ToTable();
```

The following error occurs during execution. Please advise where the problem is?

[image]

Comment: Do the solutions here work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515280/wpf-how-to-convert-from-datagrid-to-datatable

Comment: Might be a lot simpler if you keep your itemssource as whatever collection type it is originally or convert your data to a datatable and bind it's default view to the itemssource instead of however you're connecting your data now

Comment: Your cast only works if the ItemsSource binds to a DataTable. I recommend to create a DataTable from your database data instead of creating a list.

Comment: Thank you @saklanmaz This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515280/wpf-how-to-convert-from-datagrid-to-datatable  provides a good solution, This loop wants (next comment) to collect data and gets an error when it reaches the FOREIGN KEYS in the property list.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }

Comment: If you can write code like this that does not check the foreignkey, the problem will be solved.                         if (Props[i].PropertyType != ForeignKeyConstraint)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515280/wpf-how-to-convert-from-datagrid-to-datatable) as follows to ignore foreignkeys when checking properties.

```
 public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

        //Get all the properties
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
        {
            //Setting column names as Property names
            dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
        }
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[Props.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
            {
                **if (!Props[i].PropertyType.Name.ToLower().Contains("collection"))**
                {
                    //inserting property values to datatable rows
                    values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
        return dataTable;
    }
```